# Cakephp Models Naming Convention

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

Hello fellows can someone help me into this:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

I'm confused on how naming convention on Models in cakephp.

I've noticed that in the blog tutorial the model is named **"Post"** which is singular

```
class Post extends AppModel {
}
```

while in the controller the **"Post"** is **"Posts"** which is plural:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
}
```

Can someone explain this to me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's annoying, I know.

By default Cake uses pluralization on table names and controllers, but not on models. [See here for more info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html).
I made a decision early on to do away with this convention, and just go with the singular name everywhere.

I don't recommend doing this without doing a lot of research first, as it breaks the CakePHP convention and you then need to be aware of what's going on.

If you're sure that pluralization is more of a hindrance than a help, put this into your bootstrap.php file:

```
// Turn off pluralization altogether
Inflector::rules(
    'plural', 
    array(
        'rules' => array('/^([a-zA-Z_-]*)$/i' => '\1'), 
        'irregular' => array(), 
        'uninflected' => array()
    )
);
```

Comment: so for example if I want to create a "students module" I will name the model as "Student" then the controller as "StudentsController"?

Comment: @NazareneGonzales Yes. Have a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html to learn more about CakePHP's conventions.

Comment: I have a model called rate_chapters as my database table. What do I call this in Cakephp 2.4.5?

Comment: Using my system your controller is called RateChapterController, your model is called RateChapter, and you have to declare var $useTable = 'rate_chapters'; in your model.  Using the default CakePHP system the controller is called RateChaptersController, and the model is RateChapter.